# Last observation carried forward by id in R

Tags: r, locf

I have some longitudinal data like this:

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9)
var1 <- c(0,1,1,1,NA,2,2,NA,NA,NA,1,1,0,1,1,2,1,2,NA,1,1,2,2,NA,NA,2,NA)
var2 <- c(1,NA,NA,2,1,NA,1,1,NA,0,0,1,NA,0,1,1,0,0,0,NA,1,1,1,2,0,NA,2)
visit <- rep(1:3, 9)
dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, var1, var2, visit))
```

Each distinct `id` represents a patient. `visit` is the measuring cycle (i.e., each patient should be measured three times).
I would like to conduct the last observation carried forward on `var1` and `var2` by patient `id`. I found some codes in other post. It used function from package `zoo` and package `gsubfn`. It worked well for one variable (see below)

```
dt1 <- transform(dt, var1=fn$ave(var1, id, FUN= ~ na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE)))
```

I'm wondering how to do it with multiple columns? Thank you.

Comment: FYI, `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` is a bad, long way to write `data.frame(...)`. It's bad because `cbind` creates a matrix, and if you have different data types it will convert them all to the same data type.

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas, this is a data I created for this question to test if the code is working. My working data is really large so I create a smaller one to check the impute result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dplyr you can do

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(var1:var2, ~zoo::na.locf(.x, na.rm=FALSE)))
```

Comment: Suggest `dt %>% mutate(across(var1:var2, na.locf0), .by = id)`